# Getting error while fetching instance id from lambda to execute SSM document via eventbridge invocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge, aws-ssm

I want to fetch the instance id from the eventbridge rule for every new instance launch via lambda. Eventbridge rule target is lambda that trigger ssm doc for every newly launched instances.

Below is my Python code:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
client = boto3.client('ssm')
instance_id = event['detail']['EC2InstanceId']
response = client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=[instance_id],
    DocumentName='test-doc',

command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
tries = 0
output = 'False'
while tries < 10:
    tries = tries + 1
    try:
        time.sleep(0.5)  # some delay always required...
        result = client.get_command_invocation(
            CommandId=command_id,
            InstanceId=instance_id,
        )
        if result['Status'] == 'InProgress':
            continue
        output = result['StandardOutputContent']
        break
    except client.exceptions.InvocationDoesNotExist:
        continue

return output == 'True'
```

The code is triggering SSM document if we are hardcoding instance id. But not via the other way round. This is for every newly launched instance. From the eventbridge perspective, the invocation is happening as per the cloudwatch. Also, lambda has all the permissions. What way I should correct the python code so that I can get instance id from each invocation? Can anyone please help?

I tried the ways by calling the instance id in different ways:

```
instance_id = event\\\['detail'\\\]\\\['EC2InstanceId'\\\]

InstanceID = event\\\['detail'\\\]\\\['responseElements'\\\]\\\['instancesSet'\\\]\\\['items'\\\]\\\[0\\\]\\\['instanceId'\\\]
```

Getting the error as key error:

```
\[ERROR\] KeyError: 'detail' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 5, in lambda_handler InstanceID = event\['detail'\]\['responseElements'\]\['instancesSet'\]\['items'\]\[0\]\['instanceId'\]
```